# Can not update angular form that contains image

Tags: angular

I'm encountering a problem with updating data from my Angular application to a Laravel API. I have a Funder class in Angular as follows:

```
export class Funder {
  id!: number;
  name!: string;
  description!: string;
  our_products!: string;
  funding_conditions!: string;
  required_documents!: string;
  our_features!: string;
  logo!: any;
  guarantees!: string;
  financing_ceilings!:String;
  facebook_account!: string;
  linkedin_account!: string;
  email!: string;
  phone_number!: string;
  status:Status= 1;
  funder_resource_id!:number;
}
```

I'm using an Angular service with an updateFunder function to make a PUT request to my Laravel API:

```
public updateFunder(id:number, funder: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put<Funder>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/${id}`, funder);}
```

The form submission logic is handled in my component's onSubmit function:

```
    this.funderForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [this.funder.name],
      description: [this.funder.description],
      logo: [null],
      our_products: [this.funder.our_products],
      funding_conditions: [this.funder.funding_conditions],
      required_documents: [this.funder.required_documents],
      our_features: [this.funder.our_features],
      guarantees: [this.funder.guarantees],
      financing_ceilings: [this.funder.financing_ceilings],
      facebook_account: [this.funder.facebook_account],
      linkedin_account: [this.funder.linkedin_account],
      email: [this.funder.email],
      phone_number: [this.funder.phone_number],
      status: [1],
      funder_resource_id: [this.funder.funder_resource_id],
    });

    this.funderId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.funderService.getFunderById(this.funderId).subscribe(data => {
      this.funder = data;
    });

    this.funderResourceService.getFunderResources().subscribe((data) => {
      this.funderResource = data;
    }, error => console.log(error));
  }


  // Function to handle form submission
  onSubmit(){
    if (this.funderForm.invalid) {
    const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('name', this.funderForm.value.our_products);
      formData.append('description', this.funderForm.value.description);
      formData.append('our_products', this.funderForm.value.our_products);
      formData.append('funding_conditions', this.funderForm.value.funding_conditions);
      formData.append('required_documents', this.funderForm.value.required_documents);
      formData.append('our_features', this.funderForm.value.our_features);
      formData.append('guarantees', this.funderForm.value.guarantees);
      formData.append('financing_ceilings', this.funderForm.value.financing_ceilings || '');
      formData.append('facebook_account', this.funderForm.value.facebook_account || '');
      formData.append('linkedin_account', this.funderForm.value.linkedin_account || '');
      formData.append('email', this.funderForm.value.email);
      formData.append('phone_number', this.funderForm.value.phone_number);
    formData.append('status', this.funderForm.value.status);
    formData.append('funder_resource_id', this.funderForm.value. funder_resource_id);

     const logo = this.funderForm.get('logo')?.value;
  if (logo instanceof File) {
    formData.append('logo', logo);
  }

      this.funderService.updateFunder(this.funderId, formData).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log('Funder updated successfully:', data);
          this.router.navigate(['funder']);
        },
        (error) => {
          this.serverErrors=error.errors;
          console.error('Error updating funder:', error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

this is : `update.html`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-title-box">
    <h4 class="page-title">تحديث جهة الدعم</h4>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="alert" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="text-align: right">
    تم التحديث بنجاح!
    <button (click)="closeAlert()" type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">تحديث الداعم</h5>
        <div class="form-container">
          <form [formGroup]="funderForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name" class="form-label">الاسم</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" [(ngModel)]="funder.name" formControlName="name"
                [class.is-invalid]="serverErrors.name">
              <div *ngIf="serverErrors.name" class="text-danger">
                {{ serverErrors.name}}
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="description" class="form-label">الوصف</label>
              <angular-editor formControlName="description" [(ngModel)]="funder.description"
                [config]="editorConfig"></angular-editor>
              <div *ngIf="serverErrors.description" class="text-danger">
                {{ serverErrors.description}}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="our_products" class="form-label">منتجاتنا</label>
              <angular-editor  [(ngModel)]="funder.our_products" formControlName="our_products"
                [config]="editorConfig"></angular-editor>
              <div *ngIf="serverErrors.our_products" class="text-danger">
                {{ serverErrors.our_products}}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="funding_conditions" class="form-label">شروط التمويل</label>
              <angular-editor formControlName="funding_conditions" [(ngModel)]="funder.funding_conditions"
                [config]="editorConfig"></angular-editor>
              <div *ngIf="serverErrors.funding_conditions" class="text-danger">
                {{ serverErrors.funding_conditions}}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="required_documents" class="form-label">الوثائق المطلوبة</label>
              <angular-editor formControlName="required_documents" [(ngModel)]="funder.required_documents"
                [config]="editorConfig"></angular-editor>
              <div *ngIf="serverErrors.required_documents" class="text-danger">
                {{ serverErrors.required_documents}}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="our_features" class="form-label">مميزاتنا</label>
              <angular-editor formControlName="our_features" [(ngModel)]="funder.our_features"
                [config]="editorConfig"></angular-editor>
              <div *ngIf="serverErrors.our_features" class="text-danger">
                {{ serverErrors.our_features}}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="guarantees" class="form-label">الضمانات</label>
              <angular-editor formControlName="guarantees" [(ngModel)]="funder.guarantees"
                [config]="editorConfig"></angular-editor>
              <div *ngIf="serverErrors.guarantees" class="text-danger">
                {{ serverErrors.guarantees}}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="financing_ceilings" class="form-label">حدود التمويل</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="financing_ceilings" [(ngModel)]="funder.financing_ceilings"
                formControlName="financing_ceilings">
              <div *ngIf="serverErrors.financing_ceilings" class="text-danger">
                {{ serverErrors.financing_ceilings}}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="facebook_account" class="form-label">حساب فيسبوك</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="facebook_account" [(ngModel)]="funder.facebook_account"
                formControlName="facebook_account">
              <div *ngIf="serverErrors.facebook_account" class="text-danger">
                {{ serverErrors.facebook_account}}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="linkedin_account" class="form-label">حساب لينكد إن</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="linkedin_account" [(ngModel)]="funder.linkedin_account"
                formControlName="linkedin_account">
              <div *ngIf="serverErrors.linkedin_account" class="text-danger">
                {{ serverErrors.linkedin_account}}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email" class="form-label">البريد الإلكتروني</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" [(ngModel)]="funder.email" formControlName="email">
              <div *ngIf="serverErrors.email" class="text-danger">
                {{ serverErrors.email}}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="phone_number" class="form-label">رقم الهاتف</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_number" [(ngModel)]="funder.phone_number"
                formControlName="phone_number" [class.is-invalid]="serverErrors.phone_number">
              <div *ngIf="serverErrors.phone_number" class="text-danger">
                {{ serverErrors.phone_number}}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="funder_resource_id" class="form-label">مصدر تمويل </label>
              <select class="form-select" id="funder_resource_id" name="funder_resource_id" [(ngModel)]="funder.funder_resource_id" formControlName="funder_resource_id" required>
                <option *ngFor="let funderResource of funderResource" [value]="funderResource.id">{{ funderResource.name }}</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="status" class="form-label">الحالة</label>
              <select class="form-select" id="status" name="status" formControlName="status" [(ngModel)]="funder.status" aria-label="Status">
                <option value="1">Active</option>
                <option value="-1">Inactive</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <!-- Hidden file input -->
              <input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="onLogoSelected($event)" id="hiddenFileInput" style="display: none;"  formControlName="logo" >
              <label for="hiddenFileInput" style="cursor: pointer;" style="margin-top: 25px;">اختار صورة:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="logo-preview">
              <div class="circular-icon" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + (logoPreview ? logoPreview : 'https://yemenwomensguide.com/public/Admin/Uploading/images/funder/' + funder.logo) + ')'}">
                <i (click)="selectLogo()" *ngIf="!logoPreview"></i>
              </div>
            </div>


        <div class="button">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100px; font-size: 16px">
            ارسال
          </button>
        </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My API request works in Postman, but when I try to update data from my Angular application, I'm getting a 500 internal server error. The error message is:`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1…updated_at` = 2023-11-22 13:47:40 where `id` = 1)`

Comment: Seems to be primary key violation on the database